# Does anyone know how to reproduce this button with css?

Tags: css, button, transparency, opacity

I would like to create a button that when it is hovered the text become totally transparent, and the font color becomes the background image. I tried with the opacity characteristic but the problem is that the whole button turns transparent not just the text.

Does anyone have the solution?

See image for better understanding -->

[image]
Thank you in advance!

Comment: use a png background image and color:Transparent on hover.

Comment: @CarolMcKay not exactly... Color transparent will show grey text

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude if that is happening you may also need to state text-shadow:none;

Comment: @CarolMcKay no, using a background image (white border and grey background) and text to transparent, the text will be shown with the color of the background. AKA grey.

Comment: CSS-tricks has posted before [here](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/).

Comment: Where is you code?

Comment: @PeeHaa your link is webkit only. It's not good solution.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude There are several answers on there? And the question *is* an exact dupe?

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of another question, the solutions there provide the solution to this as well.